# Exchange calendar listed twice

Tags: calendar, accounts, exchange

I have one (just one) Exchange account configured:

[image: Internet Accounts preferences]

But Calendar shows it twice:

[image: Calendars tab in Calendar]

In the *Accounts* tab of the Calendar preferences it also listed twice:

[image: Accounts tab of the Calendar preferences]

and if I try to remove one of them I am *redirected* to the Internet Accounts settings (where only one is listed).

[image: Calendar warning upon account removal]

Is there a fix or should I completely remove the Exchange account and add it again?

Comment: Did a quick search for you - try the steps listed in the accepted answer here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5477854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion suggested in the comments I was able to find a *partial* solution:

1. In the *Internet Accounts* preferences (system-wide) uncheck the *Calendars* option from the Exchange account
2. In the preferences of the Calendars application choose the *Accounts* tab and disable the only visible account
3. In the system-wide *Internet Accounts* preferences re-enable the exchange account

The only drawback is that you will still see a disable Exchange account in your Calendars preferences.